# What compiler do I need to be using to build software hosted on github? [Windows]

Tags: lua

I'm trying to figure out how to create this: https://github.com/LuaDist/srlua

My understanding is you either find a binary of this which is the .exe generated from an already compiled version, or you build your own using a compiler. I can't find a binary version, thus I have to make my own.

This leaves me with a problem though: What do I use to compile and how...? I have windows 8.1 on this system, is there a program I have built-in that can do this? Do I need a certain compiler depending on the language the code is written in? Wouldn't this be written in lua? What do I need to look for in order to compile and create the program?

I'm confused cause isn't luac.exe the compiler that is shipped with lua.exe? I already have lua installed, so shouldn't I be able to use luac.exe to compile srlua? But isn't the purpose of srlua to create .exe, because luac.exe isn't able to create an .exe from anything it compiles?....so some compilers (luac.exe) can't create .exe? Is that what I am supposed to take away from this? So I need a compiler that creates an .exe (so not luac.exe), to create this srlua, so I can use srlua to create .exe of my .lua files? I'm hoping I am getting something mixed up here.

Comment: Your understanding of the term "compile" is limited. For scripting languages, compilation typically means pre-conversion to bytecode. Scripted environments can work directly with source code, but bytecode can be loaded more quickly. That's what luac does. But bytecode is not *machine* code; it's just a simplified version of the original script. It isn't directly executable. Languages like C and C++ get compiled into machine code, and thus can build executables.

Comment: This isn't really a Lua question; you need to learn how to compile from source code on your system. In particular, you need to be able to compile from C source code, but Windows doesn't come with a C compiler. You could install [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) with GCC as a C compiler, and this is the best way to get C on a Windows system, in my opinion.

Comment: I suggest you get a newer version of srlua at http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#srlua.

Comment: There's a makefile in the project, so it's probably meant to be built using `make`, but for that you need mingw (or something comparable); it will take care of calling the compiler with the correct flags for you. How to install and/or use it is a different question though and probably has many answers on SO. Alternatively you could open an issue in the github project if you feel like it could do a better job at documenting the build process.

Comment: You can find binaries and some instructions here https://github.com/noahp/srlua-mingw also take a look here for more info on rolling your own: http://stat545.com/automation02_windows.html